# issue with intvalue , floatValue

Tags: iphone

a Calculator. Each time I click on a digit button, the tag is appended to a "displaystring" nsmutable string. I ve noticed that after entering 11 digits for the same number the floatValue or intValue function give me the same error.

the self.lbldisplay.text displays the content of displaystring correctly. But the
intValue or floatValue or even the NSCanner utilities return , after entering 10 digits , the same error

here are the code and the log :

```
// original  
[self.displayString appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i", [sender tag]]];

else { // new entry      
    //origin test
    [self.displayString setString:@""];
    [self.displayString appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i", [sender tag]]];
    bIsTypingANumber = TRUE;
}

//  fCurrentNumber = [self.displayString floatValue];
//   [self display:fCurrentNumber];
// self.lblDisplay.text = displayString;

NSString *numberString; 

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithString:displayString];

NSScanner *theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];

[theScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] intoString:nil];
[theScanner scanCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] intoString:&numberString];

NSLog(@"Attempts: %i", [numberString integerValue]);

self.lblDisplay.text = str;
```

Output:

```
2012-08-26 17:23:34.264 Pilots Fuel[4989:f803] Attempts: 1
2012-08-26 17:23:34.400 Pilots Fuel[4989:f803] Attempts: 11
2012-08-26 17:23:34.552 Pilots Fuel[4989:f803] Attempts: 111
2012-08-26 17:23:34.800 Pilots Fuel[4989:f803] Attempts: 1111
2012-08-26 17:23:34.936 Pilots Fuel[4989:f803] Attempts: 11111
2012-08-26 17:23:35.072 Pilots Fuel[4989:f803] Attempts: 111111
2012-08-26 17:23:35.216 Pilots Fuel[4989:f803] Attempts: 1111111
2012-08-26 17:23:35.344 Pilots Fuel[4989:f803] Attempts: 11111111
2012-08-26 17:23:35.488 Pilots Fuel[4989:f803] Attempts: 111111111
2012-08-26 17:23:35.632 Pilots Fuel[4989:f803] Attempts: 1111111111
2012-08-26 17:23:35.776 Pilots Fuel[4989:f803] Attempts: 2147483647
2012-08-26 17:23:36.056 Pilots Fuel[4989:f803] Attempts: 2147483647
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because you overflow the integer data type, which can only hold values from -2147483648 to 2147483647 (32 bits in size). The `double` data type can hold larger values but will eventually lose precision.

Try

```
NSLog(@"Attempts: %lli", [numberString longLongValue]);
```

which will use 64 bits of precision and will allow for a larger number of digits.

Comment: Well done - I get the same "error" but much later with a very very huge number . THAAAAAAAANNNKSSS   :-)))))

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.  Please write questions that clearly state your problem.  Also, if you provide code samples, please make sure they are formatted properly so that they are more easily read by others.

Note that you are using `int` and `float` which both have size limits.  They can not represent all possible numbers.  You could use double and 64-bit integers, but they have a limit as well.  If you really need bigger numbers, see if `NSDecimalNumber` will fit your use case.  It does have a limit (though quite large).

If you need even bigger numbers, you will need to use a library that provides support for arbitrarily large numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I m trying to understand the user interface of this site and this isn't always clear to me . Thank you for your answer .